# Make "Selected Slices" the default setting when saving for web

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Whenever I save slices in Photoshop, I always have to change Slices from "All Slices" to "Selected Slices" – is there a way to make "Selected Slices" the default setting?

[image]

Comment: The thing is, it should keep the last option that you have used. Even if you close photoshop, it should still have _Slices: Selected Slices_ if that is what you used last time.

Comment: Are you using this option because each time you're changing exported slice set, or your set is basically the same but you wan't to avoid exporting some of the slices?

Comment: @Lollero Weird, in my version of CS5 it goes back to All Slices.

Comment: @thebodzio Yep, I only want to export the slices that I'm going to use.

Comment: As for the Ps "not remebering" last option, I'd try to copy your settings (Mac right? :)) from "~/Library/Preferences/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CS4\ Settings/" and delete the last folder ("Adobe\ Photoshop\ CS4\ Settings") to force Photoshop to start from defaults. Check if problem persists then. If yes, then it's not messed up settings – you can go back to your previous settings.

Comment: @timkl: so, each time your slice set changes?

Comment: @thebodzio Deleting prefs solved the problem. Thanks for helping me out! :)

Comment: Great to hear that! :D I'll put the solution in form of answer – it'll be easier to find than comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the Ps "not remebering" last option, I'd try to copy your settings (Mac right? :)) from "~/Library/Preferences/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CS4\ Settings/" and delete the last folder ("Adobe\ Photoshop\ CS4\ Settings") to force Photoshop to use installation defaults.